# jQuery add blank option to top of list and make selected to existing dropdown

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

So I have a dropdown list

```
<select id="theSelectId">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This is what I would like

```
<select id="theSelectId">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Trying to add a blank option before and set it to this, want to enforce the user to select a value from the original list but would like it to be blank when they see the option they have to choose.

Trying this but not working

```
// Add blank option
var blankOption = {optVal : ''};
$.each(blankOption, function(optVal, text) {
   $('<option></option>').val(optVal).html(text).preprendTo('#theSelectId');
});
```

and I have tried this but is clears out the other values

```
$('#theSelectId option').prependTo('<option value=""></option>');
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

This worked:

```
$("#theSelectId").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

Firebug Output:

```
<select id="theSelectId">
  <option selected="selected" value=""/>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You could also use `.prependTo` if you wanted to reverse the order:

```
​$("<option>", { value: '', selected: true }).prependTo("#theSelectId");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: It would work with prependTo as well: $("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>").prependTo("#theSelectId");

Answer (score 5):

Solution native Javascript :

`document.getElementById("theSelectId").insertBefore(new Option('', ''), document.getElementById("theSelectId").firstChild);`

example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GprybL

Answer (score 1):

To those whose would like to have the none displayed used also this:

```
$("#theSelectId").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>None</option>");
```