# How to add a value into default option in dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery

I have one dropdownlist in my page.i have to add a value "0" into "please select" option in dropdownlist.can anyone tell how to do this using jquery?
 my dropdown code is:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project.SelectedValue, Model.Project.GetSelectList(), new { @id = "jqDropDownBox" }) %>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: YOu can see in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070828/jquery-add-blank-option-to-top-of-list-and-make-selected-to-existing-dropdown

Comment: Prepend the result of your `Model.Project.GetSelectList()` function with the `0/Please Select...` option, no javascript required.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That sure is an option but I think the OP has specifically asked for a jquery based solution.

Comment: @JeevanJose What people ask for and what is best practice are usually two very different things, which is why we're here to guide people ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I do agree. Was just pointing out the specific requirement of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Add this at the end of your body tag:

```
$(function(){
    $("#jqDropDownBox").prepend("<option value='0'>Select an option..</option>");
});
```

Comment: if you put it at the end of body tag, no need to wrap it inside `$(function(){...});`

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<select id="selId">
     <option id='1' value='1'>1</option>
     <option id='2' value='2'>2</option>
     <option id='3' value='3'>3</option>
     <option id='4' value='4'>4</option>
     <option id='5' value='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$('document').ready(function() 
                        {
                            $("#selId").prepend('<option value=0>0</option>');
$("select#selId").val("0");
}
);
```

EXAMPLE JSFIDDLE LINK
http://jsfiddle.net/EwDuj/443/

Comment: i think prepend it is better here

Comment: Yes :) !! I agree!! I was so used to `.append` that i forgot this

Comment: @vignesh:can u tell how to validate dropdown here

Comment: If($("#selId").val()<=0) alert("Dropdown Blank");

Comment: Validate!? Sorry i couldn't understand your question

Comment: @vignesh: i have to show error message when user doesn't select any option in dropdown or user select "please select" option.

Comment: If you have already added this default select then it wont be empty !! so there will always be one value selected!

Answer (score 2):

You should try this one. I think It will be help you

```
 $('#jqDropDownBox').prepend('<option value="">[Select option]</option>');
```

Comment: @subash: i have to show error message near to the input field