# empty combo value with

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to put a new empty value in my combo

```
<select name="myCombo" id="myCombo">
    <option value="1">option5</option>;
    <option value="2">option4</option>;
    <option value="3">option3</option>;
    <option value="4">Other</option>;
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$('[name=myCombo]').val('');
```

doesnt work, but it does;

```
$('[name=myCobmo] option[value=1]').val('');
```

I want to change whatever the value selected is.

How  can I do it?

Comment: Seems duplicate of [jQuery add blank option to top of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070828/jquery-add-blank-option-to-top-of-list-and-make-selected-to-existing-dropdown). You may remove 'selected' attribute here.

Comment: no, that's not the same, I want to send an empty value if some conditions but not show an empty value in the combo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
$('#myCombo option:selected').val('');
```

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to had an option in your select box with an empty value ? Like this ?

```
<select name="myCombo" id="myCombo">
    <option value="">-- no value --</option>
    <option value="1">option5</option>
    <option value="2">option4</option>
    <option value="3">option3</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>
```

If yes, why do you try to do it in Javascript ?
Just change HTML.

If not, change your question coz you are not really clear =) thx

Edit : If you cant change HTML, please specify it.

Comment: no, this is not what I was looking for. Thanks anyway