# set empty on first value in combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set the first value to `null`? I used this codes but it does not work? How will I set a placeholder on combobox? Thank you in advance.

```
<select class="ddlASN"></select>
```

```js
var result = 'a,b,c,d';

$('.ddlASN').html($.map(result.split(','), function(item) {
    return $('<option></option>').val('').html('')[0].outerHTML
    return $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)[0].outerHTML
}).join(''));
```

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070828/jquery-add-blank-option-to-top-of-list-and-make-selected-to-existing-dropdown

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan hi! are you from PH? :)

Comment: yes why sir?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
    var result = 'a,b,c,d';

// placeholder option
var dd_content = '<option>-- Select an option --</option>';

// add rest of the options
jQuery.map(result.split(','), function(item) {
  dd_content += '<option value="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>';
});

jQuery('.ddlASN').html(dd_content);
```

It will prevent from getting values repeated after the submition.

If it doesn't work then please do tell what actually happens after submitting the form. Are the new values getting assigned to the combobox or not...

Comment: No problem at all ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var result = 'a,b,c,d';
    var arr = result.split(',');

    $sel = $(".ddlASN");

    $sel.append("<option></option>");
    //$sel.append("<option>PlaceHolder</option>");

    for (var i =0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {

        $sel.append("<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>")

    }

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    
   Select : <select class="ddlASN"></select>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var result = 'a,b,c,d';
    var arr = result.split(',');
    
    $sel = $(".ddlASN");
    
    $sel.append("<option></option>");
    
    for (var i =0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
        
        $sel.append("<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>")
        
    }
    
})
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when im adding a value its repeating when submiting

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set the first value to null? I used this codes but it does not work? How will I set a placeholder on combobox?

An approach you can take is to, rather than using [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which will overwrite the HTML content on each call, you use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add all the options you need, where you can use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to add values to the options and [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to add displayed text:

```js
var result = 'a,b,c,d';

// placeholder option
var placeholderOption = $('<option></option>').val('null').text('placeholder');
$('.ddlASN').html(placeholderOption);

// add rest of the options
$('.ddlASN').append($.map(result.split(','), function(item) {
  return $('<option></option>').val(item).text(item);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="ddlASN"></select>
```

**Note**: An important thing you should be aware of is that having multiple `return` statements will not work in JavaScript since any `return` after the first will never be reached.

The `map` method will take an array and convert each item based on what you return from its callback. This means you can return a new option element with the value and text set to what you need them to be, there's no need to return anything else.

Comment: when im adding a value its repeating when submiting

Comment: In that case, all you would have to do is call `$('.ddlASN').empty()` before running the code above each time you submit and it will work

Comment: Or you can just use `.html` when adding the placeholder option. This will overwrite anything that was already there